# Интеграция hmailserver и windows forms application

Tags: c#, imap, pop3

Установил и настроил *hmailserver*. Хочу написать под него клиент.

Возможна ли это? С чего начать, если это возможно?

Comment: Что именно вы хотите написать? Очередной smtp\pop клиент?

Comment: Это должен быть клиент с авторизацией, данные которые будут браться из бд hmailserver'a, функционал отправка/прием сообщений по учетной записи

Comment: А в чем отличие будет от обычного клиента? Стандартные же киенты типа `The Bat` или `Outlook` позволяют аутентифицироваться, загружать\отправлять письма. Спрашиваю чисто из любопытства, никогда не пользовался сервером `hmailserver`

Comment: У меня есть задание на курсач, создать модель почтового сервиса, функционал отправка, получение писем, добавление пользователей. Вот уже вторую сутку в поисках решений для реализации данного функционала

Comment: а, курсач. Теперь понял.

Comment: Просто как рекомендация: 1) определитесь с протоколом сообщения с сервером. Я бы выбрал pop3\imap\smtp 2) посмотрите, что из существующих решений позволяет вам делать все, что надо в плане курсача (например [первое, что гуглится](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) ) 3) выберете нужную либу  и пишите код

Comment: Я протокол выбрал, не могу настроить общение с сервером, пробую реализовать отправку письма на сервер, 0 ответа по логах